# ASP.NET - how to detect a MAC user

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-agent

I am trying to detect a MAC user using c#. I have used the following code but it always says unknown when a mac user navigates to my site. It works great for windows users but not for MAC or anything else. Does anyone have any ideas how to pick up on mac users?

Thanks

```
    HttpBrowserCapabilities moo = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<p>Browser Capabilities:</p>");
    sb.Append("Type = " + moo.Type + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Name = " + moo.Browser + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Version = " + moo.Version + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Major Version = " + moo.MajorVersion + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Minor Version = " + moo.MinorVersion + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Platform = " + moo.Platform + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Is Beta = " + moo.Beta + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Is Crawler = " + moo.Crawler + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Is AOL = " + moo.AOL + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Is Win16 = " + moo.Win16 + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Is Win32 = " + moo.Win32 + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Supports Frames = " + moo.Frames + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Supports Tables = " + moo.Tables + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Supports Cookies = " + moo.Cookies + "<br>");
    sb.Append("Supports VB Script = " + moo.VBScript + "<br>");       
    sb.Append("Supports ActiveX Controls = " + moo.ActiveXControls + "<br>");
    sb.Append("CDF = " + moo.CDF + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can extract OS information from `Request.UserAgent`.

Macintosh user agent strings are in this form:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_6; en-us)
>   AppleWebKit/528.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/528.16"
>
> "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.15; Mac_PowerPC)"

So you could do something like:

```
public bool IsMacOS(string userAgent)
{
    var osInfo = userAgent.Split(new Char[] { '(', ')' })[1];
    return osInfo.Contains("Mac_PowerPC") || osInfo.Contains("Macintosh");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Request.UserAgent` it will return something like this:
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; da; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13"..
then you will need to extract the OS

Comment: yeah I'm aware of that but it's not very helpful just having a long text string

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/operatin.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should use native ASP.NET browser caps and just extend them.

What you do is just create **App_Browsers/BrowserFile.browser** file in your ASP.NET application.

And add this to the file:

```
<browsers>
  <gateway id="MacOS" parentID="Safari">
    <identification>
      <userAgent match="Intel Mac OS X" />
    </identification>

    <capabilities>
      <capability name="platform" value="MacOS" />
    </capabilities>
  </gateway>
</browsers>
```

Doing this will be enough for Browser.Platform to return "MacOS"